# Summing cells with a variable range

Tags: excel, vba, sum, range

I have a worksheet used for my office.  Occasionally, a few extra lines are needed in one section, so I created a button that adds said line (for the non-excel users).  At the bottom of the section is a simple <=SUM(D82:D92)>.
In this way, whenever data is added, the amount is summed.

However, when a new line is added, the sum formula stays the same.  I'm trying to change the D92 to D93 (and etc.).
How can I add a line AND update the sum formula so that it stays dynamic.
Please give advice on the below code:

```
'botton cell in sum range
Dim BC As String
Dim rng As Range
BC = ActiveCell.Address
Set rng = Range(Range("d82"), Range(BC))
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
ActiveCell = WorksheetFunction.Sum(rng)
```

EDIT:
Fixed it!

```
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 3).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R82C4:R[-1]C)"
```

Comment: `"=Sum(d82:" & bc & ")"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind using a formula with `OFFSET`, you could just change `=SUM(D82:D92)` in cell `D93` into `=SUM(D82:OFFSET(D93,-1,0))`. This formula will update as expected: it will just keep looking for a reference to 1 row above itself to find the end of the sum range. E.g. a sub with `Range("D93").EntireRow.Insert` will push the formula into `D94`, now as `=SUM(D82:OFFSET(D94,-1,0))`.

---

Edit: I suggested `OFFSET`, thinking that `INDEX` wasn't possible in this case, but of course it is. Same result can be gained by using `=SUM(D82:INDEX(D82:D93,ROW(93:93)-82))` entered into `D93`. The benefit would be that `OFFSET` is a 'volatile function', which will recalculate with each worksheet change. With `INDEX`, you don't have this problem.